# SQL - Illustrative example of differences between UNION & UNION ALL in recursive CTE?

Tags: sql, recursion

I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around the difference between using `UNION` and `UNION ALL` in a recursive query. In the examples I've come across in my day-to-do, often there is no apparent difference (e.g., building a running list of integers monotonically increasing by 1), but I've been trying to understand the difference more formally using Torsten Grust's [fantastic lecture notes](https://db.inf.uni-tuebingen.de/staticfiles/teaching/ss17/advanced-sql/slides/advanced-sql-05.pdf) and the docs for Postgres and MySQL.

For example:

```sql
with recursive
     counter as (
        select 0 as i
        union all
        select i + 1
        from
          counter
        where
          i < 10
      )
select * from counter
```

returns the same results as:

```sql
with recursive
     counter as (
        select 0 as i
        union
        select i + 1
        from
          counter
        where
          i < 10
      )
select * from counter
```

I get the sensation there is a difference when doing hierarchical traversals but I can't find a good illustrative example of when the difference matters.

**Question 1**: I understand that `UNION` removes duplicate rows, but my question is *from whence* are these rows removed?

- My best guess is this is what the set difference `\` operator is doing in Torsten's slides (see comparison below).

[image: UNION in Recursive CTE]

vs.

[image: UNION ALL in Recursive CTE]

**Question 2**:  Might someone be able to offer a good comparative case that shows when a `UNION` vs. `UNION ALL` would make a big difference in a recursive query?

Comment: Noticing that in Snowflake's dialect I get the following error: `UNION not yet supported within a Recursive CTE`.